# Selecting a random string from a list results in column being populated with NULLS [SQL]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to populate a column in sql by replacing old values with new values from a list.

```
SELECT CHOOSE(ROUND(RAND() * 3, 1) + 1,'Bill','Steve','Jack')
```

Running this query gives me instances of NULLS which i don't want, why am i getting NULLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHOOSE` is just shorthand for a `CASE` expression. I talk about how an expression like `RAND()` can be evaluated more than once [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) (see the section "Expressions can be evaluated more than once"). I also talk about this [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6031/sql-server-case-expression-overview/?utm_source-AaronBertrand) (search the page for "`RAND()`").

Basically, what happens is `CHOOSE(expr, a, b)` gets expanded to:

```
CASE
  WHEN expr = 1 THEN a
  WHEN expr = 2 THEN b
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Each time you see `expr` there, it can be evaluated again. So the first time you call `RAND()` it could yield 2, then it moves to the next `WHEN`, and this time it could yield 1, then all that's left is `NULL`.

The solution is to generate `RAND()` just once, e.g.

```
DECLARE @rand tinyint = CONVERT(tinyint, (RAND()*3) + 1);

SELECT CHOOSE(@rand,'Bill','Steve','Jack');
```

Comment: Yes this makes more sense, guess i have a bit of reading to do! Thanks for the guidance on this.